# Simile Timeline with SharePoint not showing some future events when there are too many

Tags: sharepoint-2010, timeline, simile

I have a SharePoint 2010 calendar using Simile Timeline and it has about 545 events. It only shows events up to two weeks ahead of the current date (and going back one year), but there are events later than that on the calendar.

If I remove some events from the timeline then it shows some of the previously missing events. So it looks like ~545 is the max. How do I increase the max so it shows events more than 2 weeks out? I've done web searching but haven't found a solution.

Comment: Update: I've discoverd that SPServices only puts about 545 items in json.events. There are way more than that in the list. How can I get it to add more? I've looked at the CAML Query and it should be adding more.

Comment: Another update: I added the parameter CAMLRowLimit with a high value to SPServices and now it is showing all the future events. That's solved, but I'd still like to know how to make events older than a year show.

Comment: Timeline doesn't have any trouble showing events that are older than a year for me. Why not show some code?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered there was code in the CAMLQuery that was causing it so I took it out. Problem solved